# How can I reach the changeset version and pass it as argument?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I have a TFS Build Template which invokes a process after the agent has done building the application. In that process I want to pass down an argument - the changeset version.

I looked how to get that, but to no success. I saw that there are environmental variables that contain what I need TF_BUILD_SOURCEGETVERSION, but I can't find a way to reach the value. BuildDetail.SourceGetVersion, but it throws exception that it is not defined in IBuildDetail, although I see it in the msdn documentation.

How can I reach the changeset version?